# Accessing C# Form progress bar as value from another form

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

First of all sorry for my bad english.
I have a progress bar in form1 and I want the progress bar's value to increase each time the button in form2 is pressed.It can't fulfill my request even though it works without errors.I defined the progressbar as public.
I'll be happy if you can help me

```
 private void FrmAnaForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) //form 1
 {
    progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
    progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
    progressBar1.Step = 4;
 }

 private void btnEkle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //form2
 {
    FrmAnaForm af = new FrmAnaForm();  
    af.progressBar1.PerformStep();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that with every button click you create a new `FrmAnaForm` object and it seems that the form is never shown.

To help you more information is required:

x) When do you want form `FrmAnaForm` to be created and shown for user.

x) When do you want form `FrmAnaForm` to be closed/disposed.

If you edit your problem and may be of help :)

Comment: first my form1 mainform. The program closes when form1 is closed.When the button is clicked, the progress bar value in the open form1 will increase. I have a hard time understanding and explaining sorry